# Add grunt support to existing library or create wrapper plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-plugins

There is an existing NPM module that exists without Grunt compatibility. I'm interested in using it with Grunt, so I have 2 options:

- Add Grunt support to the existing project.
- Create a separate project named grunt-xxxx to wrap the NPM module.

Is one of these options better than the other?

Comment: Can you link to the library in question?

Comment: https://github.com/sideshowcoder/canned (ticket [34](https://github.com/sideshowcoder/canned/issues/34))

Comment: I would wrap it into a separate plugin myself. Simple to do. No need to burden the original project.